# Regex to split string except specified substring

Tags: java, regex, split, regex-lookarounds

I'm currently trying to split a string by whitespaces in Java, except everything between the first and last double quotes (this is a specific case and they are guaranteed to exist). I'm fairly new to regex but here's what I came up with to find the substring within the first and last quotes:

```
regex = ((?<=\").*(?=\"))
```

I have tested it out on https://regex101.com and am satisfied with the result.
But now when I try to split my input string like the following:

```
String input = "apple \"banana\"";
String[] arr = input.split("\\s+((?<=\").*(?=\"))");
```

It fails to do the actual splitting.
Here is the expected output:

```
arr[0] == "apple", arr[1] == "banana"
```

The output I recieve:

```
arr[0] == "apple \"banana\""
```

What am I missing here? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Answer has been given by @WiktorStribiżew in the comments.

A big thank you to everybody who helped, especially @WiktorStribiżew
Cheers!

Comment: You have a matching regex, so match, not split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should match these strings, here is a possible solution:

```
String input = "apple \"banana\"";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"|\\S+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
List<String> results = new ArrayList<>(); // Declare a list
while (m.find()) {
    if (m.group(1) != null) {
        results.add(m.group(1));  // Add Group 1 to the list
    } else {
        results.add(m.group());   // Add the whole match value to the list
    }
}
System.out.println(results);      // Prints the resulting list
```

**NOTE**: If you plan to match all chars between the first matched `"` till the last `"`, you may use `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"(.*)\"|\\S+");`.

See the [Java demo online](https://ideone.com/km5bVo).

Output:

```
apple
banana
```

The `"([^"]*)"|\S+` pattern [matches](https://regex101.com/r/Mob6ny/1):

- `"` - a `"` char
- `([^"]*)` - Group 1: any 0 or more chars other than `"`
- `"` - a `"` char
- `|` - or
- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply, but I have a slight complexity. There may be more double quotes within. An example would be " apple \"ban\"ana\" ". I want this to split into apple, and ban"ana. I tried changing pattern match to "\"(.*)\"|\\S+", but that didn't work out. My goal is to split by whitespace as long as they are not between the first and last double quote in the entire string. I can easily find out those indexes, but I dont know how to proceed splitting with that information. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @MalharPandya Your fix [works](https://ideone.com/bJ3MBs)

Comment: No definitely not, your answer meets exactly what the question specified, and I personally found it useful. I apologize if you thought I was ungrateful. There's just one more complexity. After the last double quote if there isn't a whitespace, I wish to include the characters till the next whitespace (or till the end of the string) also. as a part of the quoted group. Also, how do I store these groups to an array? Thank you.

Comment: Edit: I think I found the answer, the regex is : "\"(.*)\"*[\"]|\\S+". Now just need to store it in an array. Thank you for giving me the approach @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @MalharPandya I am not sure about `"\"(.*)\"*\"|\\S+"`, it does not seem to make any difference. `"\"(.*)\"|\\S+"` must work the same. Please consider sharing a test case for that. I updated the code to collect the matching chunks into a list.

Comment: Sorry for not being able to reply sooner. The method fails to stop splitting on whitespaces within the quotes. For example, if user input is "apple ban\"ban  ana\"man pear" then the expected output is [apple, ban"ban ana"man, pear], but the recieved output is [apple, ban"ban, ana"man, pear].

Comment: I found that \"[^.]*\"|(\s+) matches the required whitespaces, but also matches the quoted substring. Is there a way to remove a specific match (the quoted one for this instance)? Because then I can simply add that to the regex and proceed with input.split("\\s+('regex here')"). Thank you

Comment: @MalharPandya `\S*".*?"\S*|\S+`? See https://regex101.com/r/UZay1g/1 and https://ideone.com/aFSkMM

Comment: YES! this is perfect. Thank you very much, I will update the answer soon!

Answer (score 0):

```
"\\s*\"++|\\s++"
```

apple "banana"' =>     2 [[apple, banana]]

Comment: Here also regex seems fine. Am I missing something?Why this also got downvoted?May be explanation wise...or something?